# C# service not starting on first reboot

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, server

I have a windows service written in C# 4.61.  On a unpatched Windows 2008R2, Windows 2012R2, or Windows 2016 server it refuses to start automatically on the first reboot after install.

I even have it set to Automatic (Delayed Start) and it still gives the error:

```
Entry 1

A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for (servicename) service to connect.

Entry 2

The (servicename) service failed to start due to the following error: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

On any reboot from then on it starts with no issue.

I know that the proper thing would be to patch the system, however I would like to be able to identify what hotfix/update corrects this problem.

Throughout all the searching that I have done, most people suggest to extend the global service timeout to correct this issue, and that is not acceptable for me to go changing global settings on someones production machines.

I know that the issue is not how long my service takes to start, as manually starting it only takes a few seconds.

Comment: The main thing I'd suggest here is : do even less during start. Defer most things to a separate thread - maybe see if the only things you need to do in the start loop is check the config to see that you *should* be able to start.

Comment: I have even started the entire service process in a thread, this should let it start almost instantly.  However I ran into the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
{
    this.YourFunction();
});

private void YourFunction()
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: This was one of the solutions that I initially tried, no difference.